# SQL Divide number of ID's from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql

I have the following problem, I have 2 tables:

```
Surveys (surveyID, topic, text)
Response (responseID, response_text, response_value)
```

My problem is the following: how do I get the average number of responses per survey?

Assuming I have 2 `SurveyID` and 8 `AnswerID`, how can I divide the 8 `responseID` by the 2 `surveyID`?

My thought was but this does not work out:

```
SELECT (COUNT(surveyID) / COUNT(responseID)) 
FROM Surveys, Response;
```

Comment: I think your database design is flawed, and there should be some relationship between the survey and response tables.  Also, tag your question with the actual database you are using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server).  SQL is just a language, not a product.

Comment: What is the error? or the output you got is unexpected

Comment: Okay thankt you, I'll be more accurate the next time :-) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja the output is unexpected, the result I get is '1'.

Comment: `SELECT (COUNT(distinct surveyID) / COUNT(distinct responseID)) 
FROM Surveys, Response`. The only reason being for unexpected output is the duplicates seperately in your tables use this youll get the desired.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with sql-serevr:

```
with x as(
Select count(*) as totSurveys, 0 as TotResponse
from Surveys
union
Select 0 as totSurveys, count(*) as TotResponse
from Response
) select TotResponse/totSurveysas Result
from x
```

or you can :

```
select (Select count(*) from Surveys)/(Select count(*) from Response)
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen mhe, thought i was on sql-server tag, edited solution for sql-server

Answer (score 0):

To be very specific on your question:

```
SELECT (COUNT(distinct surveyID) / COUNT(distinct responseID)) 
FROM Surveys, Response;
```

(the distinct intructs the DBMS to count only unique values from the result)

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT (COUNT(distinct surveyID) / COUNT(distinct 
   responseID)) 
   FROM Surveys, Response
```

> The only reason being for 
>               unexpected output is the duplicates seperately in 
>                 your 
>                tables use this youll get the desired